# Custom date formats in webform emails

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

I have a webform that sends an email. The webform has a date field and I need to format that date field.

I have tried:

```
[submission:values:date_field:CUSTOM_FORMAT]
[submission:values:date_field:long]
[submission:values:date_field:value:custom:d-M-y]
```

Both result in a blank date.

How can I format the date in a webform email using a non-default (which appears to be `short`) date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a custom [hook_tokens](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7) function:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_tokens().
 */
function MODULE_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();
  if ($type == 'submission' && !empty($data['webform-submission'])) {
    $node = isset($data['node']) ? $data['node'] : node_load($submission->nid);

    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'values:date_field:custom_format':
          foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $cid => $component) {
            if ($component['form_key'] == 'date_field') {
              $replacements[$original] = format_date(strtotime($data['webform-submission']->data[$cid][0]), 'custom_format');
            }
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```